# How do I mount a guest Samba share on Ubuntu?

Tags: mount, samba

I have a public (guest enabled) Samba share running on my local network from my Xubuntu server. I can access this on my Xubuntu 22.04.02 linux client with Thunar using the path smb://hostname.local/path. Accessing the share in this way, I have full read/write access, as intended (and do not need to enter a username or password).

The Samba config is:

```
[myshare]
    comment = myshare
    path = /srv/samba
    read only = no
    guest ok = yes
    browsable = yes
    public = yes
    writeable = yes
    local master = yes
    preferred master = yes
```

I would like to mount the share to make it possible to access via the file system. I am using the following command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //hostname.local/path /mnt/ftp1/ -o guest,rw
```

I get the following error:

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
```

I'm at a loss on what to differently on the mount command. Grateful for any pointers.

Comment: I used your mount command and it did work on my system; I do not know the server configuration. Should in your command 'myshare' instead of 'path'? Or try to change the /mnt/ftp1 path to some other existing empty directory in your home

Comment: I made some folder ownership changes on the server, so the command now works. But I'm still not able to create a writeable mount, despite having write access without credentials via Thunar smb://. It's the inconsistency between being about to doing something one way, but not another that baffles me.

Answer (score 0):

> But I'm still not able to create a writeable mount, despite having
> write access without credentials via Thunar smb://.
>
> sudo mount -t cifs //hostname.local/path /mnt/ftp1/ -o guest,rw

**rw:**

That option is redundant since it's the default.

It makes the mount write-able. Not to anyone only to the owner of the mount which is root.

You have many options:

***Replace root as owner with you***

*This is what the Thunar method of access is doing.*

```
sudo mount -t cifs //hostname.local/path /mnt/ftp1/ -o guest,uid=morbius
```

***Make it so all local users can access the mount:***

```
sudo mount -t cifs //hostname.local/path /mnt/ftp1/ -o guest,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0666,nounix
```

***You can even make it so that only members of a given group can write to the mount and others can only read:***

```
sudo mount -t cifs //hostname.local/path /mnt/ftp1/ -o guest,uid=morbius,gid=plugdev,nounix,dir_mode=0775,file_mode=0664
```

*morbius can write, all members of the plugdev group can write, and everyone else can only read.*

Many possibilities.